# angular ng-class on a conditional expression for a $scope variable in the controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I need to apply a class based on the length of a scope variable

```
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <i class="float-right" ng-class="{'user-online':activeAssignments.length > 0, 'user-offline': activeAssignments.length <= 0}"></i>
</div>
```

Could i do something like this or is there a better way of doing this?

`$scope.activeAssignments` is defined in the controller

Comment: Yes, you *could* do this.  Are you having a problem or issue with this solution?

Comment: the page crashes once i add this

Comment: What does the error say in the console?

Comment: no error in teh console...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would at least take that logic out of the HTML and use a simple function on the controller:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <i class="float-right" ng-class="onlineClass(activeAssignments)"></i>
</div>
```

and on the controller

```
$scope.onlineClass = function(a) {
    return (a > 0) ? 'user-online' : 'user-offline';
};
```

Comment: after this, the page does not crash any more